# Text border and shadow together

Tags: html, css, border

I searched quite a bit, how can I write text with a border and shadow border simply, could not find a solution that combines border and shadow well together.

like this:

[image: a busy cat]

Finally I decided to implement it that way.

```
text-shadow: -2px -2px 0 #fff,
              2px -2px 0 #fff,
              -2px 2px 0 #fff,
              2px 2px 0 #fff,
              0px 0px 8px #000;
```

[Here the example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ItEmq)

This is a good solution or someone can improve it?

Thanks

Comment: this solution is perfect bro.

Comment: That's the best solution you can find. Go ahead and use it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a -webkit that deals with this issue that worked really well for me:

```
  -webkit-text-stroke: 3px black;
```

You can even change the colour with a similar -webkit:

```
-webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
```

Checkout more on this at [CSS-TRICKS](https://css-tricks.com/adding-stroke-to-web-text/)